# How to parse google custom search result get throug Json by using restfull api to Google results as google shows?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, google-custom-search

I want to parse the json get through google custom search restful api into results as google shows in its search result .

I am using ajax for the service call but don't know the way to parse there result in Google Search Result Format ...
here is my Code

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function (){
      $.ajax({
        url: https:www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyDETpXCuhV0RsUtqiM5i8GB0EZ_v_bLNLs&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=<?php echo $val; ?>&alt=json,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(json_data){
          //Whats Efficient Way to Parse the Code In HTML as
          //Google SHows In search Results
          alert(data);                  
        }); 
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your json_data as follows:

```
alert(jQuery.parseJSON(json_data));
```

Answer (score 0):

we can also use jquery for this...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

            var data = GetURLParameter('search_data'); //that data we passed for google search

            $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=your key&cx=YOUR CX&q='+data, function(resp)
            {

                 var i=0;

                 while(i<=10)
                {
                    var title=resp.items[i].title;
                    var link=resp.items[i].link;


                    alert(title);

                    i++;
                }

            });
});

function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```